# What are the ScheduledExecutorService limitations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thread-safety

I'm new to threads management and task scheduling and I have a particular situation where i need to run a user triggered command after a specific delay in my Spring Boot project. 
I found out that i can use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` as such:

```
public void userTriggeredAction() {
    ... do somthing
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(()-> doSomethingAfterDelay(), 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

My question is what are the limitations of this approach considering the fact that the `userTriggerdAction()` might be lunched by a considerable number of users (in the thousands) at the same time ?

Regards.

Comment: One limitation is that since you have a pool of 5, only 5 tasks will ever be running at once.  NOTE: I assume you are sharing this ScheduledExecutorService otherwise you will run out of resources pretty quickly.

Comment: Without more information, I would have one pool of 1 to 4 threads, and reuse it.  No need to create more threads than you have cores.

Comment: You'll context-switch yourself to death with a pool of 5000 threads. Choose a number more suited to the cores in your server and back it up with an appropriately sized blocking queue that has a defined rejected execution policy.